# filter admin access by IP with httpd.conf

Tags: users

I am trying to filter all backend url to one IP in the httpd.conf file using this piece of code :

```
<Location /admin>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 100.x.xxx.xxx
</Location>
```

This one works fine. But I can't find a way to do the same with /?q=admin.

```
<Location /?q=admin>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 100.x.xxx.xxx
</Location>
```

Do I need some regular expression with backslash to escape some of the characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem you're having is that `<Location>` (and `<LocationMatch>`) directives don't operate on query strings (the thing that comes after the `?`) -- See [This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019594/apache-locationmatch-match-query-string) & [The Apache docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/mod/core.html#location).

You can accomplish the same thing using `mod_rewrite` and some creativity - [There's even an example of access control based on query string](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString) in the docs.

Something along the lines of what's below should be close to what you need.

```
# Applying for all query strings (admin|user)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=.*
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !0\.1\.2\.3
# Something is missing here (result: domain.com/page?q=admin) but it works because the link dies anyway on an error page
RewriteRule ^(.*) /page [QSA,L,R=301]
```

Comment: I just succeeded to make it work with a few changes. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @user2123664 Feel free to propose an edit with a more correct set of rules -- especially if I botched the syntax (I didn't think too hard & didn't test it, so there's a 50% chance what I wrote above won't even load as a valid rule :-)

Comment: Sure, here it is :`code`
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^q=.*
    RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !0\.1\.2\.3
    RewriteRule ^(.*) /access-denied.html [QSA,L,R=301]`code`
I choosed to include all query strings starting with ?q= because it could apply to ?q=user also. Then my redirection is doing wrong, but it goes on an error page, so at this point I am satisfied with it. I guess something is missing after /access-denied.html because in the url it rewrites like this /access-denied.html?q=admin/